# Using LIEF to change OEP

Tags: python, binaryfiles

After playing for a while with [LIEF](https://lief.quarkslab.com/doc/stable/index.html), I have stumbled upon a problem I cannot manage to solve. The steps are apparently simple:

1. Identify OEP in a PE File (Done)
2. Create new section in the PE File (Done)
3. Create a inconditional jump (JMP) in the new section, pointing to the OEP (???????)
4. Modify OEP to point to the new section (Not done, but seems easy)

My main problem is with step 3, as I cannot ascertain based on LIEF documentation if there is some way to provide LIEF with ASM code and it will take care of it, or if I need to pre-compile the ASM instruction and then providing LIEF with the hex equivalent.

What is the easiest way to do this?